# Socket.io handle Client internet off event

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Socket.io how to handle client internet disconnect event? 
I read [heartbeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119691/socket-io-specifying-heartbeat/31787022#31787022) on stackoverflow but that solution does not work for me.

I found a [ping solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119691/socket-io-specifying-heartbeat/31787022#31787022) but I think it is a bad approach to ping all the connected user, it will slow down the server

here is my code, kindly guide how to handle internet disconnect event?

```
io.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.on('online', function(data) {
        socket_api.user_online(data.user_id, function (err,res){
            if (err) {
                client.emit ('error',err);
            } else {
                console.log ("client connected")
                client.emit ('online_response', res);
            }

        });
        // client.emit('messages', 'Hello from server');
    });
    client.on('disconnect', function (data){
        console.log ("Client disconnected");
    });
});
```

Comment: `ping-pong` based solution is required for `websocket`

Comment: When the client loses its internet connection, the server will get a disconnect event.  It might not be immediate, but it will happen.  I think your question is probably a dup of this: [how to detect that user's connection is lost or he closed the browser window in Nodejs socket.io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293520/how-to-detect-that-users-connection-is-lost-or-he-closed-the-browser-window-in) and this one [Socket IO detect when client has lost connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182695/socket-io-detect-when-client-has-lost-connection).

Comment: Please guide me the ping solution will not effect the node server performance? Is it a good approach ?

Comment: socket.io already does ping and pong and will detect a lost connection in its default configuration - you do not have to add more ping/pong.  There are socket.io configuration parameters that control how often ping and pong are set and how long the socket.io server code waits before declaring a lost connection.

Comment: if it detects connection lost after some time, then what is the real time left in it ? It will be no more real time then

Comment: @jfriend000 after connection lost it marks user disconnect after 2mins

Comment: Can you please tell me how to reduce the time for marking user disconnect ? 
What exactly socket is doing is, when user lost connection it marks the user disconnect after 2mins, I want to reduce this delay to 1min

Answer (score 1):

```
 // use this on server side
function sendHeartbeat(){
    setTimeout(sendHeartbeat, 8000);
    io.sockets.emit('ping', { beat : 1 });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('pong', function(data){
        console.log("Pong received from client");
    });
}

setTimeout(sendHeartbeat, 8000);
```

.................................................

```
// on Client side 
socket.on('ping', function(data){
          socket.emit('pong', {beat: 1});
        });
```

hope this help you

Comment: Can you please tell me how to reduce the time for marking user disconnect ? 
What exactly socket is doing is, when user lost connection it marks the user disconnect after 2mins, I want to reduce this delay to 1min

Comment: Please read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708604/nodejs-socket-io-connections-dropping-reconnecting)

Comment: @majeet, but this code does not have disconnect event? How will it handle? Can you please explain ?

Comment: on internet disconnect no event fire by Client so you need you predict by ping pong method.

Comment: why we are using io.socket.on() why not io.on
what is the difference ?

Comment: Please read Socket Doc for proper explanation [link](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/)

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew Yes, Use this in development phase or as per your requirment in production